# Thymeleaf page not rendering properly on successful Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm a started to Thymeleaf and jQuery/ajax. What I was trying to do was creating a login form. On successful login, API returns JWT token and in the subsequent API calls use the JWT token in the 'Authorization' request header. Adding the jQuery for login page below.

```
    $("#login-form").submit(function (event) {
        
        event.preventDefault();

        var loginForm = {}
        loginForm["username"] = $("#user").val();
        loginForm["password"] = $("#pass").val();
        

        $("#btn-login").prop("disabled", true);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/login",
            data: JSON.stringify(loginForm),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("jwt_token ", data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home",
                    headers: {'Authorization' : data},
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 600000,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("Home page api success");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        
                    }
                });
                
            },
            error: function (e) {
            }
        });
        
    });

});
```

Adding the controller file below.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {
  
  
  @GetMapping("/login")
  public String showLoginPage() {
      return "login";
  }
  
  @GetMapping("/home")
  public String showHomePage(HttpServletRequest request) {
      final String jwtToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      System.out.println("token" + jwtToken);
      return "home";
  }

}
```

Here I'm facing 2 issues.

1. On successful login, I'm not redirecting to home page. It's still there in login page. But I could see the JWT token getting printed in browser console.
2. I could not get the authorization header in my controller.Controller prints the value of token in console as token[object Object].

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your first problem,

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
     .authorizeRequests()
     // ... endpoints
     .formLogin()
     .loginPage("/login.html")
     .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
     // rest...
}
```

You can give a name to your home page in the defaultSuccessUrl method.

For the second problem, you should be able to receive the string value of 'Authorization'. Nothing wrong in your showHamePage method.

I suspect that the problem arises from AJAX response/request. I think you receive "jwt_token" in JSON format and you send this whole JSON data without parsing. You need to parse first and give the value to headers - Authorization field.